# Password Hashing in Ruby/ Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

this is my first post on stack. I am just curious as I have read regarding password hashing and more often I was told to use BCrypt instead. However, are there any documentations that I can use in order for me to try and hash the passwords on my own? I know using BCrypt is optimal for safety reasons but I would like to play around and understand the codes or functions surrounding hashing a password when the user signs up without using BCrypt or any other gems.

For this, I have tried using 'SecureRandom' and 'Digest' but I still seem to be unable to get the desired output. Perhaps I am still new at this.

This is my codes. I am very new at this.

```
require 'digest'

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else

    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, password_hash([:password]))
  end

  def password_hash(password)
    hash = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(password)
  end
end
```

Once I convert it into strings, the password column in the database will be empty after the user sign up. I know my codes are a messy but I would like to try to encrypt the passwords without using gems.

Comment: Your question has no relation to your code. "I have tried using `SecureRandom` and `Digest` but I still seem to be unable to get the desired output." What did you do, and what was the desired output? The concept of hashing is easy, but particulars of any decently strong algorithm that would be okay to use in practice are quite complex. Basically, for real world, the golden rule of cryptography is to only ever use cryptography libraries written by professional cryptographers, never make your own (unless you happen to be one of the small minority of people who understand it thoroughly).

Comment: @Amadan Hello thank you for your response. Perhaps I phrase it wrongly. The desired output is that when a user signs up, their password will be automatically hashed instead of it being spelled out in the Database. That was the desired output. Also, right now I am lost as where to find documentations on cryptography regarding ruby. Either I am not proficient at googling or I am just a noob..

Comment: We cannot see what you did wrong in your hashing code if we can't see your hashing code. You can see documentation on Ruby's crypto methods in the API docs for individual hashing methods; for example, in docs for BCrypt gem.

Comment: @Amadan hey, i have edited my post so you can see what i was trying to do. I hope that can shed some light in what I am trying to accomplish..

Answer (score -1):

My team always use Devise gem for work with users. It simple for using and have 
great functional as: password encrypt, send email, authorization and other